# should wildcards belong to CNAME or A NAME?

Tags: subdomain, wildcard, cname, wildcard-subdomain

should wildcards belong to CNAME or A NAME? Both looks the same to me, and googling gives me a inconclusive result.

Any rational and implications behind for choosing one over the other? (underlying DNS server software? web hosting software? speed?)

Comment: I voted to close: "belongs on serverfault.com".

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it practically matters.

A wildcard can be used for any DNS record type, so it's not a wildcard for *.domain it's a wildcard only for the particular record type.

[RFC 4592](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4592)
covers them in extreme detail.

Answer (score 2):

You can add wildcard in both A records and CNAMES.

The typical example of why would you want to add a wildcard in A records is when you have dedicated IP address, say 1.2.3.4.

if someone were to visit http://wildcard.mytestdomain.com, and the subdomain "wildcard" does not exist, the server will respond with the IP address specified as the wildcard.

`A        *        1.2.3.4`